# Signalr: Tracking User State across page requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I'm trying to implement instant messaging using Signalr in a ASP.NET webforms site.

I have made a good start so far, I can send a message from one client to another without any issue.

My problem comes from maintaining chat windows across asp.net requests.

When a user has a chat window open and navigates to a new page on the site, this counts as a disconnect and new connect to the signalr hub. (Client gets new ConnectionID).

This is a problem as it means I cannot determine weather this is a users first connect (no chat window open, just logged into site) or if they had an active chat window and just changed page.

If they just changed page I would like to keep the chat window open with messages showing. I can reconstruct the conversation from our database, but have no way to know if this conversation should be shown or not.

I have considered using some sort of timeout mechanism (if this conversation was active within the last X minutes, then show it on new page) but this seems to me to be a bit unwieldy.

As I can't save the active conversations in OnDisconnect (as this cannot take any arguments) I would have to use some sort of polling mechanism to save a timestamp of the last time the conversation window was open.

I was wondering has anyone run into any similar problems, and if they have, how did they approach them.

Any help is appriciated...

Comment: Could you pass a variable of the conversation id (and any other information you need) in a query string when navigating between pages?

Comment: Is there a way to add query strings to each link on a page from javascript? It's a rather large site, and I'd be wary of using jQuery to modify each link...

Comment: Not to mention when some of the page changes come from response.redirect on the server-side...

Comment: Although, come to think of it I could use cookies to save conversation IDs. I'll try this and post an answer if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Use cookies to track the active conversation ID between page requests. Has added benefit of using timeout even if person logs out and then in again within a specified timeframe.

Thanks to cdslnte for triggering the thought...